# How to set input defval for a source that name that is used by more than one added indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have an strategy that has bollinger bands, and Keltner channels.  The names of the sources are such as "BB: Basic" or "KC: Basic" etc. I want to set a default input source using one of these. Right now I have this type of input line in my code:

kc_basis = input(close, "KC Basis")

I have to go in to the widget input area and change the "close" source to "KC: Basis" each time I change the script or start it up again. I have a bunch of these and it is tedious each time. I would like to set the default to "KC: Basis" but I see no way to do this and the documentation doesn't go into this particular type case. How can I set the defval to "KC: Basis". You can set the default to close or high or one of the other build in values from the current bar but for added indicators, I don't see how you do it. Any ideas?

Note the source I want is basis from the KC indicator thus pine script labels it "KC: Basis" in the widge input screen to distinguish it from other indicators that have a indicator field of Basis (BB: Basis is another one I am using.

I tried using quotes "KC: Basis" but pine code doesn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. The default value must exist.

If you refer to an external source, there is no guarantee that that source will be available. What should happen when KC or BB is not on your chart? There is no "second default" value.